# What is the header file for Legacy_MAP_MASK in mmap( )

Tags: linux, mmap

I want to know the header file which contains the LEGACY_MAP_MASK  in mmap( ), and also the bits of all the flags in the LEGACY_MAP_MASK. I searched a lot but was unable to find it. Thanks:).

I included the header file #inlcude<sys/mman.h> and I tried to assign, like
unsigned long map = LEGACY_MAP_MASK. But it throws the error ‘LEGACY_MAP_MASK’ undeclared (first use in this function).

Answer (score 1):

Its `mman.h`, you can include `#include <linux/mman.h>` to get the [LEGACY_MAP_MASK](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux/include/linux/mman.h#L35) macro.

```
/*
 * The historical set of flags that all mmap implementations implicitly
 * support when a ->mmap_validate() op is not provided in file_operations.
 */
#define LEGACY_MAP_MASK (MAP_SHARED \
                | MAP_PRIVATE \
                | MAP_FIXED \
                | MAP_ANONYMOUS \
                | MAP_DENYWRITE \
                | MAP_EXECUTABLE \
                | MAP_UNINITIALIZED \
                | MAP_GROWSDOWN \
                | MAP_LOCKED \
                | MAP_NORESERVE \
                | MAP_POPULATE \
                | MAP_NONBLOCK \
                | MAP_STACK \
                | MAP_HUGETLB \
                | MAP_32BIT \
                | MAP_HUGE_2MB \
                | MAP_HUGE_1GB)
```

Comment: Included the header file #include<sys/mman.h>, but I am unable to use like unsigned long flags = LEGACY_MAP_MASK, as it throws LEGACY_MAP_MASK undeclared.

Comment: @VijayAntony, which Kernel version you have ? `uname -a` output ?

Comment: Linux debian 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @VijayAntony, the macro is actually defined in linux kernel header mman.h. If you are including it in a kernel scope module you should find it, else you are not suggested to try include kernel header from user space.