# How to solve the mmap( ) failed with unexpected error EPERM ( 1 )

Tags: c, linux, unix, mmap

When I run the below program I get that the mmap() fail with the EPERM error. My expected O/P is EOPNOTSUPP error, as any flag outside the LEGACY_MAP_MASK flag would fail with EOPNOTSUPP.

```
#define TEST_FILE "file_to_mmap"
#define TEST_FILE_SIZE 1024
#define TEST_FILE_MODE 0600

unsigned long  legacy_flags;
unsigned long  map_flags;

int fd_file;
void *mapped_address;

fd_file = open(TEST_FILE, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, TEST_FILE_MODE);
legacy_flags = LEGACY_MAP_MASK;
map_flags = ~(legacy_flags) + MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE;
mapped_address = mmap(NULL, TEST_FILE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, map_flags, fd_file, 0);
if (errno == EOPNOTSUPP)
   printf("Have a nice day");
```

Error:

```
mmap( ) failed with the unexpected error: EPERM (1)
```

uname -a: O/P:

```
Linux debian 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63773647/440558) the `LEGACY_MAP_MASK` macro contains 17 flags. On a 64-bit system `unsigned long` is 64 bits, meaning `~(legacy_flags)` will turn on 47 *other* bits. Some of which might have meaning, and possibly require elevated privileges (which is why you get `EPERM`).

Comment: . ` ~(legacy_flags) + MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE;` What are you trying to do? It does not make sense to invert `legacy_flags` and set with that every other flag. And when a 1 bit in `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE` is lower then the lowest bit set in `legacy_flags`, the bit becomes set again, because you use an addition. `|` and `&` would make more sense then additions when you deal with bits.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude, Could you please tell me some suggestions to get this done.Thanks:).

Comment: What is it that you're even _attempting_ to do here, @VijayAntony? Get an error?

Comment: @ AKX, I am trying to check that if any flag other than the flags present in LEGACY_MAP_MASK is present in the argument along with the MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE the  mmap( ) throws EOPNOTSUPP .